# assign a function into a variable and run itself

Tags: javascript

I have read a interested blog where this above technique is applied, i understand it will run the function itself. but what's the purpose assign to a variable, when i try to console.log the variable i get **undefiend**.

```
var test1 = (function(){
    console.log('yay')
})();

console.log(test1)
```

what's the differnet doing this way below

```
(function test1(){
     console.log('yay');
})();
```

Suggestion are appreciated. :)

Comment: The function has no return value, so the assignment to `test1` is useless. In the second example, the name `test1` is immaterial, as the function is being immediately executed. It works exactly the same if you don't specify a name at all.

Comment: Info: Naming the function, like in the second example, can be useful when performing stack traces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The immediately invoked function expression (IIFE) in Javascript serves to introduce a closure via a new scope. This is often done to compensate for the lack of block scoping in Javascript or provide information hiding a la module pattern (seen often in jQuery plugins).

Minimal example below:

```
var counter = (function() {
    var i = 0;

    function inc() {
        i++;
        return i;
    }

    return inc;
})();
```

The return exposes assigns the function `inc` to the variable `counter`. Successive invocations of `counter()` will result in 1, 2, etc. while keeping `i` hidden.

This is roughly equivalent to an object oriented approach that declared `i` as private.

Comment: Thanks peakxu this make a lot sense to me now

Answer (score 1):

In your sample above the function is **void** which makes no sense to assign the function result to a variable since it is returning nothing:

However tweaking your sample a little bit:

```
var test1 = (function(){
    console.log('yay'); return "hello";
})();
```

then it makes sense since `test1` will return `"hello"`.

So in your original sample there are not differences and the fact that you assign a the result of a function which is not returning values is a bit odd.

Comment: This return make sense why it assign to a variable. Thanks Dalorzo